# Strange GCC warning on storage class and type

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a header file that looks like

header.h

```
int TOS;
```

This file is being included by just one code file

code.c

```
#include "header.h"
TOS=0;
```

When compiling code.c GCC issues a warning

code.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
code.c:3:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘TOS’ [enabled by default]

I fail to understand the cause of this warning. Isn't it equivalent to declaring and defining TOS in code.c? i.e.

code.c

```
int TOS;
TOS=0;
```

Comment: You do have a `main()` right?

Comment: Yes main() is there. Just omitted it for brevity.

Comment: And the `TOS=0;` is *inside* `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you define `TOS` in the global scope, which need you to define the type of `TOS`(it is an declaration), if no type was given, by default it is `int`.

This will cause an `conflicting type error`,

```
char x;
x = 0;
```

Comment: But why can't one declare a a global and define it later??

Comment: @I think it is because the compiler only allows variables declaration and initialization in global scope but not assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to forward a variable in a header file would be

```
extern int TOS;
```

without the `extern` this could otherwise result that `TOS` is allocated in several compilation units (.o files).

You'd then give a definition in one .c file as

```
int TOS;
```

This would then reserve space for it and since it is a variable in global scope it also would initialize it to `0`. If you want to make this initialization explicit or if you want it to be to another value than `0`, the correct syntax for initialization (and not *assignment*) is

```
int TOS = 54;
```

Modern C doesn't allow the syntax that you seem to have inherited from somewhere, namely a definition of a global variable with implicit type `int`.

Comment: While `TOS` would have been allocated in several translation units, in C (but not in C++), the linker should collapse them into one.

Comment: @ninjalj, no I don't think so. This would only be the case when there is no initialization, I think. **If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression .. somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.**

Comment: `int TOS;` from `header.h` is a tentative definition with external linkage. You can include `header.h` from several translation units and  the linker will collapse them into one.

Answer (score 0):

`TOS=0` is not an assignment, it's a declaration with an initializer (i.e: a definition). `int TOS;` is a tentative definition with external linkage. When the linker links several translation units together, it collapses the corresponding object (=memory for a variable). As said elsewhere, the default type of `int` is a C89 feature absent from later editions of the standard.

Comment: Nope. First there is no such thing like a tentative declaration in the C standard, there are *tentative definitions*. And then tentative definitions require that there is no initializer: **A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative definition.**