# warning: data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have a file `global.h` which is included across many files in the project and contain general headers. The relevant contents of file is given below:

```
#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
extern int debug_level;
#endif
```

It has been included in `main.c` and there is a warning corresponding to the following line in `main.c`

```
#ifdef DEBUG            
debug_level = 6;   //compiler generates warning corresponding to this line.
#endif
```

The warning message issued by compiler is:

```
src/main.c:14:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
src/main.c:14:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘debug_level’ [enabled by default]
```

I do not understand what is that I am doing wrong. Surprisingly the program works fine because I think that compiler assumes that the number is an `int`(by default).

Comment: where are you defining this variable??

Comment: Does `main.c` actually include `global.h`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange GCC warning on storage class and type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703260/strange-gcc-warning-on-storage-class-and-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define as `int` as

```
#ifdef DEBUG            
int debug_level = 6;   //define as int
#endif
```

With your code, its implicitly defined as `int`, hence the warning.

And `extern int debug_level;` is not definition but a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just set the variable in global scope, you actually have make a *definition* that matches the *declaration* in the header file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG            
int debug_level = 6;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `debug_level` as `external` if it is already declared some where else. Then the compiler will look for the declaration on other places also.

```
#ifdef DEBUG            
external int debug_level = 6;
#endif
```